# Given an array of intergers arr and Queries, find all subsequnce of queries in array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of integers **arr** and an array of queries **queries**, where each query represents a triple of integers. Find the number of occurrence of each query as a sub sequence in the given array arr.  Note**  each query length will always be 3.

```
For arr=[1,2,2,1,2,1,2] and queries = [[1,1,2],[1,2,1]]. The solution would be [4,6] 

(0,3,4) == 1,1,2 = 1
(0,3,6) == 1,1,2 = 1
(0,5,6) == 1,1,2 = 1
(3,5,6) == 1,1,2 = 1 
Total = 4 

Will go through Same Step for query at index 1 and the sum will be 6.Therefore the solution would be [4,6]
```

Comment: Add your current approach to the question

Comment: What are the constraints?